# Running Spring Boot Native Application on Azure Functions: Permission denied with server.port: 80

Tags: spring-boot, azure, docker, azure-functions, spring-native

I have created a simple Spring Boot Application and compiled it with Spring Native `gradle bootBuildImage`. I uploaded the docker container to an private registry and deployed it to Microsoft Azure Function. Accessing the function will correctly start the Spring Boot Application inside the docker container. But it crashes with following exception:

```
2021-11-09T15:46:55.996267267Z 2021-11-09 15:46:55.996  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.nativex.NativeListener               : This application is bootstrapped with code generated with Spring AOT
2021-11-09T15:46:55.997230973Z 
2021-11-09T15:46:55.997396574Z   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2021-11-09T15:46:55.997539875Z  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2021-11-09T15:46:55.997679976Z ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2021-11-09T15:46:55.997816777Z  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2021-11-09T15:46:55.997979078Z   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2021-11-09T15:46:55.998114779Z  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2021-11-09T15:46:55.999546489Z  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.6)
2021-11-09T15:46:55.999559889Z 
2021-11-09T15:46:56.065075944Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.054  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application using Java 11.0.13 on 421026966d15 with PID 1 (started by cnb in /workspace)
2021-11-09T15:46:56.065102544Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.056  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-09T15:46:56.095177553Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.094  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-11-09T15:46:56.097067866Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.096  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-11-09T15:46:56.147529016Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.147  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
2021-11-09T15:46:56.148811625Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.148  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.149445829Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.148  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.54]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.154613565Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.154  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-11-09T15:46:56.155352670Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.154  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 95 ms
2021-11-09T15:46:56.177839326Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.177  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.179695539Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.179  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-11-09T15:46:56.181115849Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.180  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-11-09T15:46:56.183164263Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.182  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-11-09T15:46:56.533544294Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.533  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-11-09T15:46:56.534665902Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.533  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2021-11-09T15:46:56.675326478Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.675  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.676515986Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.676  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-09T15:46:56.722262803Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.722  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-11-09T15:46:56.746931074Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.746  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
2021-11-09T15:46:56.749313091Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.749  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-09T15:46:56.750124797Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.749  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-11-09T15:46:56.877499580Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.877  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-11-09T15:46:56.878593388Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.877  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888123954Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.880  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888151454Z 
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888156354Z Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888160554Z 2021-11-09 15:46:56.880 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888164954Z 
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888168654Z org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888172954Z  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:5.3.12]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888177354Z  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:5.3.12]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888181254Z  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888196454Z  at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888200454Z  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:5.3.12]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888204354Z  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:5.3.12]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888208354Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888212155Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888216155Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888220055Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:2.5.6]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888224455Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:2.5.6]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888228555Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:2.5.6]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888232355Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:2.5.6]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888236255Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:2.5.6]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888240055Z  at de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt.main(BuchschrankApplication.kt:17) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888243955Z Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888247755Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888251555Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888255455Z  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:5.3.12]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888259455Z  ... 14 common frames omitted
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888263155Z Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888266855Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:238) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888270755Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888275055Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888281755Z  ... 16 common frames omitted
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888285555Z Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888289355Z  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1075) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888293055Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888296855Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:234) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888300655Z  ... 18 common frames omitted
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888304255Z Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888308255Z  at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST_SocketException_constructor_df417f52c09624a386e25e5af85993f853394076(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888312255Z  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Net.java) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888315955Z  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888319655Z  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:447) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888323255Z  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888327055Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:271) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:9.0.54]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888330955Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:226) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:9.0.54]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888334755Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1208) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:9.0.54]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888338655Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1294) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:9.0.54]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888342555Z  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614) ~[de.aditu.buchschrank.BuchschrankApplicationKt:9.0.54]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888346355Z  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1072) ~[na:na]
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888350255Z  ... 20 common frames omitted
2021-11-09T15:46:56.888353856Z
```

Regarding the logs, Azure starts docker with

```
docker run -d -p 7502:80...
```

The first port seems to be random.

The full source code can be found here: https://github.com/lesestunden/buchschrank-backend

Does anybody have an idea whats going wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: On Linux, ports <1024 can be opened by root only. Instead, try 8080 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application should listen on a non-privileged port (> 1024).

The created container is unable to use a [privileged port](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html). The `bootBuildImage` task creates and runs images utilizing buildpacks (for runtime [paketobuildpacks/run:tiny-cnb](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/stacks/tree/main/tiny/cnb/run)), the application in the container doesn't run as root. Therefore you can not listen on a port below 1024.

Spring boot uses [paketo-buildpacks](https://paketo.io/), which have some security-hardenings in them

> The stack images are run as a dedicated non-root user when building
> and running applications.

see [paketo documentation](https://paketo.io/docs/concepts/stacks/#what-security-and-hardening-features-do-paketo-stacks-offer)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is using a port bigger than 1024 (e.g. 8080) and configure the port like in this answer: [Azure Functions with docker: How change port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69915834/azure-functions-with-docker-how-change-port)